# order by filed that matches string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL database that contains a table called 'users' with a column called `industriesrepresented`

on my page, I have a string like `$myindustry = '97'`

in the field in my DB, users select from various industries which each have a unique id. `ie - 97,89,83,44,42`

I'm then running a query `(SELECT * FROM`users`)`

but I would like to put it in order and display the users that have got for example '97' entered in the column 'industriesrepresented'

and put them at the top of the list.

hope this makes sense

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this?

Comment: It's maybe time for you to think about DB normalization

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE`.

```
...
ORDER BY concat(',', industriesrepresented, ',') LIKE '%,97,%' DESC
```

The expression will yield an (implicit) Boolean, that is `1` if 97 is in the column `0` otherwise. Since `1` > `0` you have to use `DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY find_in_set("'.$myindustry.'", industries)  DESC
```

Another solution

```
select * 
from users 
order by (case industries when "'.$myindustry.'" then 0 else 1 end)
```

Comment: @user3783243 The first would be an expression that returns 0 if the row is the one you want or 1 if it isn't. Sort will be ascending so you get your preferred record first.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how a DB is supposed to be used.

First, think about the relations between `users` and `industries`.

- An unique user can represent 0 to many (n) industries.
- A single industry can be represented by 0 to many (n) users.

The relation between users and industries is (0, n) - (0, n). Commonly called **Many To Many**

You have 2 tables, `users` and `industries` that can be represented this way :

**users**

```
 id | name
```

**industries**

```
 id | name
```

In SQL, to build this kind of relationship, you need a 3rd table that contains the foreign keys **of both tables**

**users_industries**

```
user_id | industry_id
```

To avoid duplicated entries, the primary key of the 3rd table is the **composition of both FK**

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id INT(6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE industries
(
  id INT(6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE users_industries
(
  user_id INT(6) NOT NULL,
  industry_id INT(6) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (industry_id) REFERENCES industries(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, industry_id)
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES (default, "John"), (default, "Jane"), (default, "Bob"), (default, "Mary");

INSERT INTO industries VALUES (default, "Renault"), (default, "Peugeot"), (default, "Citroen"), (default, "Venturi");

INSERT INTO users_industries VALUES (1, 1), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 4);
```

---

**Query #1** : How to get all users with their respectives industries ?

```
SELECT u.id AS "User id",
       u.name AS "User name",
       i.id AS "Industry id",
       i.name AS "Industry name"
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN users_industries ui
ON u.id = ui.user_id
LEFT JOIN industries i
ON i.id = ui.industry_id
ORDER BY u.id;
```

**Output**

```
| User id | User name | Industry id | Industry name |
| ------- | --------- | ----------- | ------------- |
| 1       | John      | 1           | Renault       |
| 1       | John      | 3           | Citroen       |
| 2       | Jane      | 1           | Renault       |
| 2       | Jane      | 2           | Peugeot       |
| 2       | Jane      | 3           | Citroen       |
| 2       | Jane      | 4           | Venturi       |
| 3       | Bob       | 2           | Peugeot       |
| 3       | Bob       | 3           | Citroen       |
| 3       | Bob       | 4           | Venturi       |
| 4       | Mary      | 4           | Venturi       |
```

---

**Query #2** : How to get the industries names of a specific user ?

```
SELECT i.name AS "Industry name"
FROM industries i
LEFT JOIN users_industries ui
ON i.id = ui.industry_id
WHERE ui.user_id = 3
ORDER BY i.id;
```

**Output**

```
| Industry name |
| ------------- |
| Peugeot       |
| Citroen       |
| Venturi       |
```

---

**Query #3** : How to get the user names of a specific industry ?

```
SELECT u.name AS "User name"
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN users_industries ui
ON u.id = ui.user_id
WHERE ui.industry_id = 3
ORDER BY u.id;
```

**Output**

```
| User name |
| --------- |
| John      |
| Jane      |
| Bob       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9mfNVSLGQDYggjM8Yy3nFE/0)